# Extract decimal value from sql

Tags: javascript, android

I have a series of values that I want to extract from sql table and I am stuck at price which is decimal. I don't understand how to do this. So I have this:

```
int currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
String currentProduct = cursor.getString(productColumnIndex);
int currentPrice = cursor.getInt(priceColumnIndex);
int currentQuantity = cursor.getInt(quantityColumnIndex);
String currentSupplier = cursor.getString(supplierColumnIndex);
int currentPhone = cursor.getInt(phoneColumnIndex);
```

Currently I have price set as an integer but in my sql table is set it to decimal. How can I extract it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Double currentPrice = cursor.getDouble(priceColumnIndex);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the price to be an `int` type in your application code, then you could call `.intValue()` on the extracted decimal.